# struts2 :Creating checkbox list based on user selection in dropdown

Tags: jsp, struts2

i have a double select dropdown list:

Code is :

```
< s:doubleselect name="cluster.name" list="clusters" 
listKey="name" listValue="name"
doubleName="application.name" 
doubleList="applicationsPerCluster.get(name)" 
doubleListKey="name" doubleListValue="name" />
```

Here list clusters is Cluster List and where each Cluster is having List of Servers.

I need to display List of Servers as Checkboxes based on the Selected Cluster in dropdown.

How to get the selected cluster value in the same JSP? And how i can form a list of servers as checkboxes . List of server are available in Cluster Object.

Please let me know

Comment: Forget about S2 doubleselect and implement it using javascript.

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply.. there is no problem with double select..
I need to create a list of check boxes based on user selected value from the drop down...How to get the selected value in another tag

Comment: fire an ajax request on select change and pass the selected value to action and then in ajax-response, you may choose to return checkboxes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788247/how-to-set-an-arraylist-object-in-a-dropdown-through-ajax

Comment: i have one map, which contains the list of server, i just need to pass the key , but key is coming from the dropdown. How to get the get the drop down value in another tag or in the same JSP

Comment: Thanks for your replies,
I am able to fix the issue, through javascript and ajax