# how to set an ArrayList object in a dropdown through ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, struts2, html-select

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>


<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
  <!-- <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="10;URL=regd.action">  -->
    <title>cascading dropdown</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="getDeptNameUsingId.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="#" method="get" id="regdform" name="regdform">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><strong><em><font color="#800000">Department of the user</font></em></strong></td></tr>

                    <tr >
                    <td><strong>Department :</strong></td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="department" style="color: #800000;font-size: medium;width:150px" onchange="findDeptDetails2(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value="">-----------------</option>             
                <c:forEach items="${allLocations}" var="x">
                    <option value="${x.getVch_LevelName()}">${x.getVch_LevelName()}</option>
                </c:forEach>
                    </select>
                    </td></tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td><strong>Line Department :</strong></td>
                    <td>
                    <select  name="linedepartment" id="linedepartment" style="color: #800000;font-size: medium;width:150px">
                    <option value="">-----------------</option>
                    </select>


                    </td></tr>

                    <tr>
                    <td><strong>Office :</strong></td>
                    <td><select name="office" style="color: #800000;font-size: medium;width:150px">
                    <option value="">-----------------</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    </select></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><strong>Section :</strong></td>
                    <td><select name="section" style="color: #800000;font-size: medium;width:150px">
                    <option value="">-----------------</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    </select></td></tr>

                    <tr><td><strong>Designation :</strong></td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="designation" style="color: #800000;font-size: medium;width:150px">
                    <option value="">-----------------</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    </select></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><strong>Grade :</strong></td>
                    <td><select name="grade" style="color: #800000;font-size: medium;width:150px">
                    <option value="">-----------------</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    </select></td></tr>
                    <tr><td><strong>Physical location :</strong></td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="physicallocation" style="color: #800000;font-size: medium;width:150px">
                    <option value="">-----------------</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    </select></td></tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><strong>Employee type :</strong></td>
                    <td>
                    <select name="emptype" style="color: #800000;font-size: medium;width:150px">
                    <option value="">-----------------</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    </select></td></tr>
    <tr>                
   <td> <input type="submit" value="submit"/></td></tr>


    </table>

    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

getDeptnameUsingId.js

```
    function findDeptDetails2(v){

        var xmlhttp;
        if(v=="")
            {           
            document.getElementById("linedepartment").selectedValue="";
            return;
            }
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {
            xmlhttp=new  XMLHttpRequest();
            }
        else
            {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                var y=xmlhttp.responseText;


                var x=document.getElementById("linedepartment");

                var option=document.createElement("option");
                option.text=y;
                try
                  {
                  // for IE earlier than version 8
                  x.add(option,x.options[null]);
                  }
                catch (e)
                  {
                  x.add(option,null);
                  }

                    }



        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","linedept.action?q="+v,true );
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

action class

```
package action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import connection.AdminLevelDetails;

public class DropDownData {
    private List<AdminLevelDetails> allLocations;
    private List<AdminLevelDetails> allDepts;
    private String location;
    private List<String> allDetlocation;






    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }


    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }


    public List<AdminLevelDetails> getAllDepts() {
        return allDepts;
    }


    public void setAllDepts(List<AdminLevelDetails> allDepts) {
        this.allDepts = allDepts;
    }


    public List<AdminLevelDetails> getAllLocations() {
        return allLocations;
    }


    public void setAllLocations(List<AdminLevelDetails> allLocations) {
        this.allLocations = allLocations;
    }



    public String execute()
    {
        try {
            SessionFactory sf=(SessionFactory)ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getAttribute("sfkey");
            Session s=sf.openSession();
            Query q=s.createQuery("from AdminLevelDetails where int_PIdId=0");
            allLocations=(ArrayList<AdminLevelDetails>)q.list();



            /*Query q1=s.createQuery("from AdminLevelDetails where int_PIdId=1 and int_LevelId=2");
            allDepts=(ArrayList<AdminLevelDetails>)q1.list();*/


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "success";
    }


public String lineDepartmentDetail()
{
    try {
        SessionFactory sf=(SessionFactory)ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getAttribute("sfkey");
        Session s=sf.openSession(); 
        Query q1=s.createQuery("from AdminLevelDetails where int_PIdId=1 and int_LevelId=2");
        allDetlocation=(ArrayList<String>)q1.list();
        Iterator itr=allDetlocation.iterator();
         while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(itr.next());
            }
        HttpServletResponse response=ServletActionContext.getResponse();
        response.getWriter().println(allDetlocation);
        //allDepts=(ArrayList<AdminLevelDetails>)q1.list();

        //response.getWriter().println(name);


    /*  HttpServletRequest request=ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        HttpSession hs=request.getSession();
        hs.setAttribute("username", name);
        hs.setAttribute("userid", uid);*/

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;



}







}
```

first i have index.jsp  in my first drop down in onchange event i call  ajax in javascript file i want to set the arraylist value in second dropdown but in bellow code only object are appeared in dropdown

Comment: try option.text=y.toString(); in your JS code

Comment: `lineDepartmentDetail()` what does it return ?

Comment: paste your html source-code